# Prolonged time with dead CMOS battery

Tags: motherboard, battery, cmos

Today my CMOS battery died (typical symptoms: date reset on cold boot, asked to press F1 on startup)

I already have a replacement, however I would really like to avoid changing it, as my motherboard is a Z77 Sabertooth, and I'd have to remove everything to open the thermal armor and get to the battery.  Plus, I usually keep my PC connected to the power outlet, and in that case the BIOS doesn't reset.

Is there any risk to the computer if I don't change the battery (I don't mind pressing F1 once in a while)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep it that way, it's not going to *harm* anything.

However, if you have any custom settings, you are going to lose those every time you shut down/power off.

Everyone's usage is different, so it may not matter to you.  However, for me, I remote in and issue WOL packets to start up my machine.  Having it stop at F1 would be a game ender for me.  YMMV.

Comment: I've seen dead CMOS batteries leak, so it isn't totally without risk.

Comment: @fixer1234 How frequently does this happen in your experience? How old were the batteries you've seen leak? My battery just died, so it is about 5 years old

Comment: @SebastianoRoncato, I don't recall seeing it with batteries that had just died, but I've seen it a few times with really old batteries that were left in long beyond their expiration.  True, it can be a pain in the butt to access and change them in some cases, but they last about 5 yrs, so it isn't necessary often.